# Q/ evaluate (d/dx)ln |tan x| .

Tags: derivatives

Q/ evaluate (d/dx)ln |tan x| .

If we apply this theorem ([image] )

then we will have just = ( 1/tan x )

But in the book they solve it like this ( [image] )

So, what i'm asking about it is, why they but more ( tan x ). It's the green one

Comment: Chain rule...${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Mitra's comment points out, what you are looking for is the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule). Basically, the key aspect is that, in general,
$$
(f\circ g)^\prime(x) \neq f^\prime( g(x) )
$$
but instead
$$
(f\circ g)^\prime(x) = f^\prime( g(x) ) \cdot g^\prime(x)
$$
(when $f,g$ are differentiable). It is not sufficient to differentiate the "outer function": a simple example is, say, for $f\colon x>0\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ and $g\colon x>0\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ (so that $f\circ g(x) = x$ for all $x > 0$). Clearly, this implies $(f\circ g)^\prime(x) = 1$ for any $x > 0$; yet $f^\prime( g(x) ) = -x^2$, as $f^\prime(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$.